# Update iOS app description after release without changing the app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

After the release of an app in the iTunes store, is it possible to change the description of the app without updating the whole app again?

So is it possible to change the images or the text of the description, save the changes and update the shown description inside the iTunes store?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because app store policy questions should be directed at Apple.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Update** 
As Sam commented this behavior seems to have changed recently (maybe with iOS 11 App Store Changes?) so it is no longer possible to update the App Description without an App Update. The Description field is now "locked" for apps that are in Ready For Sale state. Other metadata fields continue to be editable as specified in the official documentation linked below.

[image: Locked Description Field]

**Original**
As RJH mentioned in a comment, you CAN actually update the description (as well as the Marketing and Support URL) for an app version already in the app store.

Here's the link again with direction to the specific section:
https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devfc3066644

In order to do this, from within your App in iTunes Connect you must:

1. Select the specific app version (left sidebar)
2. Update the description field
3. Don't forget to click Save!

Apple doco says your changes are posted immediately and should be reflected in the App Store within 24 hours.

Comment: This must have changed, because right now I can't change the description for my app which was just released. It looks like I have to push an entirely new version. The description field has a padlock icon next to it. I *can* update the "what's new in this version", url, and copyright notices though.

Comment: Thanks for the update Sam! Just checked myself and you're right that they now lock the description for Apps in Ready For Sale state. That's pretty frustrating especially given that the documentation on this hasn't been update (though that's not particularly surprising).

Comment: @Sam can we update release notes by keeping manual release and submitting for review ??

Comment: I gotta say this is just pure madness by Apple.

Comment: I agree with Sean. Apple will not let me fix a typo in my store listing description unless I release a new version of the app! Madness.

Answer (score 20):

**Update:**
My answer from 2015 became incorrect after a few years. Link also doesn't work anymore.

**Original:**

> "**Can be edited at any time.** To edit this information, select the Ready for Sale version from the platform header in the left pane, edit
> the desired field and then click save. Changes will reflect on the App
> Store within 24 hours."

Citation from:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppMetadata.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH3-SW46

Comment: can we update release notes by keeping manual release and submitting for review ??

Answer (score 11):

[You **can** edit the description at any time for an app that has already been approved](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppMetadata.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH3-SW46)

To do so:

- Login to iTunes Connect
- Click **My Apps**
- Click the app icon for the app you want to edit
- In the left hand menu, [click on the ***x* Ready For Sale**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWDbe.png)
- Edit the description as needed and click **Save** in the top right
  corner

Changes will immediately reflect in iTunes Connect, but can take up to 24 hours to reflect in the App Store.

Comment: I cannot edit the descripion of a ready for sale app. Description is disabled and I see a lock near the label.

Comment: I have the same issue as @Sabrina, app is Ready For Sale, published to app store almost exactly 12 hours ago

Comment: can we update release notes by keeping manual release and submitting for review ?????

Comment: Same for me, the description is "locked" : grey and not editable :s

Answer (score 9):

Now you cannot change:
What's New in This Version,
Description,
Any app info.

You still can change:
Promotional Text,
Copyright,
Address.

https://9to5mac.com/2018/03/20/change-whats-new-text-app-review/

Answer (score 3):

If Your App status over itunesConnect is **"Waiting For Review"**,You can change your description but other than this status you have to upload a new build by creating a new version.

Comment: Im not convinced this is correct due to this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppMetadata.html#

Are we sure ??

Comment: As @maciej-hawryluk answers, it is possible **at any time**

Comment: I cannot change my description, my app is ready for sale and was published almost exactly 12 hours, there is actually a padlock account left top corner of the Description textbox

Answer (score 3):

Now you can't update the **App Description** once the App is **Ready For Sale**. You have to push a new build for this change.
All editable and non-editable fields information can be found [here](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devfc3066644)

Answer (score 0):

You don’t have to upload a new build. Just click “cancel this release “. Description can be updated now. Save and submit again.