# Change `What's New in This Version` after app is `Ready For Sale`

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have released one version of my application on `iTunesConnect`. I have written some description under `What's New in This Version`, but by mistake, there is spell error.

So now I need to correct that spelling error as it is app's reputation need to maintain.

Can anyone suggest, how to do this?

I have read many questions and answers here, but those all are too old... before 2-3 years. I want to know, if now can change or not and how?

Comment: see this for help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602442/update-ios-app-description-after-release-without-changing-the-app

Comment: @Anbu.karthik Thanks for comment, but they are talking about `Description` and I need to change `What's New in This Version` text.

Comment: are you seen the link, the answer is avilable , you can't change the text in ready for sale, you need to add another build for the change.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of April 2018, it is no longer possible to edit "What's new in this version" without [submitting a new version and going through app review](https://9to5mac.com/2018/03/20/change-whats-new-text-app-review/):

> Apple is today informing developers of a new policy change through iTunes Connect. From April, the ‘What’s New In This Version’ text and the support URLs in App Store listings will no longer be able to changed at will.
>
> Changes to this metadata will now require a new app update to be submitted to the App Store.